# Show that $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}A_r\right)=1$

Tags: probability

> Let $A_r$, $r\geq1$, be events such that $\mathbb{P}(A_r)=1$ for all $r$. Show that $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}A_r\right)=1$.

---

For this question, I used induction to show $\bigcap\limits_{r=1}^{n}A_r$ is a decreasing sequence of sets, then let $n$ approaches to infinity, i.e. $$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}A_r\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigcap\limits_{r=1}^{n}A_r\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_r)=1$$

---

My question is: since each $\mathbb{P}(A_r)=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$, from my intuition, I think $A_r=\Omega$ for all $r$. Somehow, I don't think this is right but I don't have a counter-example.

I also computed $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}A_r\right)=1$ as well. Then I wonder what probability model satisfy this question.

Comment: Here's a counterexample: Take $\mathbb{P}$ to be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Then $\mathbb{P}((0,1])=1$, but $(0,1]\neq[0,1]$.

Comment: Somewhat more exciting example: consider your favorite probability measure on the real line that has a PDF, say the standard gaussian distribution, and $$A=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$$

Answer (score 2):

What $P(A_r)=1$ means is that it differs from $\Omega$ only by null sets.

An example would be something like this:

$$A_n := \mathbb{R}\setminus n$$
if we let $\mathbb{P}$ the the measure associated with the gaussian distribution, then

$\mathbb{P}(A_r) = 1$ but $\Omega \setminus A_r \neq \emptyset$